# How to loop through JSON request in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter for performance testing & stuck at a point. I have to process a request with multiple users & before I process the request to an API endpoint, I have to iterate on all users & need to update the "ConsentDate" to system.DateTime. So please help me with a solution, i am a beginner to the jmeter framework.

I am trying to take help of **JSR223 PreProcessor** .
Please find the screen shot.
[Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCvaV.jpg)

I am reading the json from a CSV file & My request structure looks like below,

```
{
"Company": {
    "User": {
        "u1": {
            "id": "1001",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "consentDate": "2020-03-14T17:44:56.224Z"
        },
        "u2": {
            "id": "1002",
            "consent": "No",
            "consentDate": "2020-03-14T17:44:56.224Z"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, that's very easy, please find the screen shot

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

Text version of the code just in case, going forward please post code as text, not as image:

```
def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def now = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
request.Company.User.each { user ->
    user.getValue().consentDate = now
}
def body = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(request).toPrettyString(), '', false)
body.setAlwaysEncoded(false)
data.addArgument(body)
sampler.setArguments(data)
```

Comment: Its is not working, its not able to update the request payload property. e.g def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
def request = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
def now = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
request.Applicant.each { aplc ->
    aplc.getValue().AccountNumber = "12"
}
def body = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(newRequest).toPrettyString(), '', false)
body.setAlwaysEncoded(false)
data.addArgument(body)
sampler.setArguments(data)

Comment: change `newRequest` to `request`

Comment: Still it is not working sir